# php code for excluding @ # $%^&*

Tags: php

How can I exclude @ # $%^&*  from a given string?

Comment: You mean excluding like removing or like not allowing?

Comment: The `pls sent me the code`, `pls help me` parts in your question are not needed (and generally frowned upon here). Just ask jour question in a serieus manner and you'll get answers here (dont't beg for them - please ;-)

Comment: A better way to think about this kind of question is to have a clear list of things you DO PERMIT in your string, and to either detect something not in that list and fail, or remove everything not in that list and recover and continue - largely depending on what you have told your users on the form/their value to you/your perception of their motives for sendng you these chars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$str= preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9_\-\/=]+/", "", 'your string here');
```

This allows only common acceptable chars. Excludes the chars you mentioned.

Or you can try this too:

```
$str = '@ # $%^&*';
$new_str = str_replace(array('@', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&', '*'), '', $str);
print $new_str;
```

Comment: You don’t need to escape the `.` and `?` inside a character class.

Answer (score 5):

You can specify multiple characters to replace using [`str_replace`](https://www.php.net/str_replace):

```
$s= 'what a @bad #$%^ string *';
$s= str_replace(array('@', '#', '$', '%', '^', '%', '*'), '', $s);
echo($s);
```

This will ouput:

```
what a bad  string
```

Answer (score 5):

A simple regular expression would be one way to do it:

```
$str = preg_replace('/[@#$%^&*]/', '', $str);
```

Comment: Using regex here is like using a cannon to kill a fly.

Comment: Is it? It's shorter to write and faster to execute that any other way I can think of.

Comment: Faster than a simple `str_replace()` or a `strtr()`?

Comment: @Lukáš: +1 You're right, sorry. I benchmarked it and it's `preg_replace()` is slightly faster due to the slow array instantiation on `str_replace()` and `strtr()`.

Comment: It depends on how you benchmark and on what platform i guess. For me the `strtr()` is actually the fastest.

Answer (score 1):

```
$thisIsaVeryBadStringIndeed = "@wh#at %a b^a&d @#$%^&*string";
$unWantedBadCharacters = "@#$%^&*";

$chars = preg_split('//',$unWantedBadCharacters);

for ($i=0;$i<strlen($unWantedBadCharacters);++$i)
    $pairs[$unWantedBadCharacters{$i}] = '';

$stringWithoutBadCharacters = strtr($thisIsaVeryBadStringIndeed,$pairs);
```

This is one of the faster methods. If you only create the pairs array once.

Comment: Oh and yes, i know i am not replacing individual characters. Was that really the question?

Comment: I interpreted the question as "@ # $%^&*" being a string, because why would you have two spaces in there?

Comment: @#$%^&* Actually I dont want this to be considere as a string but as inividual characters which can take place anywhere in a string an any number of times.. how to replace these characters..

Thnks or your help